# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen „räubern“, „stehlen“ und „klauen“?

Tags: meaning, difference, synonym

Ich weiß bereits, dass „stehlen“ „to steal“ bedeutet und „klauen“ eine informelle Version dafür ist. Aber was ist mit „räubern“?

Comment: Das Wort »räubern« (kleingeschrieben) gibt es im deutschen Wortschatz nicht. Es gibt das Verb »rauben« (englisch: *to rob*), und es gibt das Wort »Räubern« (mit großem Anfangsbuchstaben), das ist aber ein Substantiv im Dativ Plural (»Ich gebe den Räubern was sie verlangen«).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Doch. Zumindestens in der Umgangssprache gibt es das Wort *räubern* sehr wohl, und es ist für den Duden auch nichts neues. Es wird als "wohlwollend betrachtetes" "klauen" oder "mopsen" verwendet: "Die Kinder! Die kleinen Racker haben mir die ganze Keksdose leergeräubert" - Auch wenn der Duden eher eine "klassische" Haltung zur Bedeutung hat.

Comment: @tofro: Du meinst aber das Wort »leerräubern«, das ungefähr gleichbedeutend mit »ausrauben« ist. Ich schrieb aber, dass es das Wort »räubern« nicht gibt. »Der beschäftigungslose Ernst Wimmer bedrohte die Rentnerin mit einem Messer und wollte ihr die Handtasche *räubern*.« Das passt wohl eher nicht. Es muss heißen »... wollte ihr die Handtasche *rauben*.«

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Hubert, du bist spitzfindig. Dann nimm "Die Kinder! Die kleinen Racker haben mir alle Kekse aus der Dose geräubert". *räubern* funktioniert wesentlich besser mit Keksen als mit Handtaschen.

Comment: Ich habe dazu eine Frage formuliert: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/37550/1487

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. *stehlen* ist das Wegnehmen von Sachen, die jemand anderem gehören - Typischerweise heimlich, ohne dass es jemand merkt. *Diebstahl* ist ein offizielles Delikt, das so auch im Strafgesetzbuch steht.
2. *klauen* ist dasselbe wie *stehlen*, jedoch ein umgangssprachlicher Ausdruck. Es hat eine (leicht) weniger kriminelle Notation und wird eher für den Diebstahl kleinerer, weniger wertvoller Dinge verwendet (Trotzdem kann man ein Auto *klauen*).
3. *rauben* ist das Wegnehmen von Sachen, die jemand anderem gehören, unter Androhung oder Anwendung von Gewalt - also nicht heimlich. *Raub* ist ebenfalls ein offizielles Delikt, das im Strafgesetzbuch steht.
4. *räubern* ist die Tätigkeit des *Räubers*, also traditionell ein nahes Synonym von *rauben*. In Texten aus dem 19. Jahrhundert wird es im Sinne von "fortgesetztes Räuber-Sein" verwendet, eher nicht für eine Einzeltat - An sich veraltet, wird aber noch zum Beschreiben von eher harmlosen "Delikten", wie Mundraub im Garten oder das Leerräumen einer Keksdose, vor allem von Kindern verwendet.

Dann gibt es noch *stibitzen*, *mopsen*, *jd. um etwas erleichtern*, die alle irgendwo in der Nähe von *klauen* und *räubern* in der Schwere des Delikts liegen.

Answer (score 10):

Es gibt einen Unterschied im Recht: Im Gegensatz zum **Diebstahl** ist es für den **Raub** notwendig, Gewalt anzudrohen oder anzuwenden.

Im alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch wird dieser Unterschied nicht gemacht.

> Dieser Computer **raubt** mir den letzten Nerv.
>
> Der Papierkram **stiehlt** einem nur die Zeit.

**Räubern** ist eine Verniedlichungsform des *Raubens*.

> Die Vögel haben mal wieder meine Kirschen **geräubert**.
>
> Für die Kinder gibt es kostenlos eine Gabel und einen leeren Teller zum **Räubern** bei den Erwachsenen.

Comment: Echt jetzt? »Die Vögel haben mal wieder meine Kirschen *geräubert*«? Wo sagt man sowas?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Heute praktisch überall in Deutschland. Traditionell eher im Norden.

Comment: Ich habe dazu eine Frage formuliert: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/37550/1487

Comment: @tofro  Ich komme aus dem Süden, und mir ist das Wort durchaus geläufig, insbesondere für Fälle, die einer übertragenen Bedeutung von *wildern* nahestehen: so etwa 'gegen explizite oder stillschweigende Vereinbarung in einem fremden Bezirk tätig werden und dem dort ansässigen Akteur Einkommens- oder Nahrungsquellen entziehen'. In meiner Sprachumgebung würden man *stehlen* etc. üblicherweise mit Akkusativobjekt verwenden, *räubern* typischerweise ohne ein solches, aber mit einer Ortsangabe (wo räubern?).