# Verbreitung des Verbs »räubern«

Tags: word-usage

In Kommentaren zur Frage »[Was ist der Unterschied zwischen „räubern“, „stehlen“ und „klauen“?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/37546/1487)«, und auch in einer Antwort zu dieser Frage wurde behauptet, es gäbe das Verb »räubern«, und eine kurze Recherche hat ergeben, dass zumindest [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A4ubern) und [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/raeubern) dieses Verb ebenfalls kennen.

Mir persönlich war es bisher aber nicht bekannt. Ich hielt es für eine fehlerhafte Ableitung eines Verbs aus dem Substantiv »Räuber«. Ich kann mich nicht entsinnen, dieses Verb in einer Konversation zwischen deutschen Muttersprachlern gehört oder irgendwo gelesen zu haben (abgesehen von einer ganz bewussten Verballhornung).

Daher bin ich mir ziemlich sicher, dass dieses Wort im Osten Österreichs nicht in Verwendung ist.

Auch im Rest des deutschen Sprachraums kommt das Verb in gedruckten Werken nicht besonders häufig vor, wie dieses [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rauben%2Craubte%2Cgeraubt%2Cr%C3%A4ubern%2Cr%C3%A4uberte%2Cger%C3%A4ubert&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crauben%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Craubte%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgeraubt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A4ubern%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A4uberte%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cger%C3%A4ubert%3B%2Cc0) zeigt:

[image: Ngram: rauben, raubte, geraubt, räubern, räuberte, geräubert]
<sub>Die Formen *rauben, raubte, geraubt* kommen ca. 100 mal häufiger vor als die Formen *räubern, räuberte, geräubert*</sub>

**Meine Frage:**
Wo, innerhalb des deutschen Sprachraums, wird dieses Verb verwendet, und in welchen Situationen?

Comment: Vorsicht: Tatsächlich dürfte die Anzahl von Fundstellen noch niedriger sein - Googles Scanner kommt mit gebrochenen Schriften nicht so richtig klar und hält des öfteren ein "langes s" für ein "r", findet also auch *gesäubert*

Comment: Ich persönlich wüsste genau eine Stelle, wo das Verb *räubern* regelmäßig gebraucht wird, nämlich um das etwas sperrige Wort "Mundraub" zu vermeiden. Dagegen ist *rauben* bei den ganzen Krimis ein alltägliches Wort.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zunächst: In meinem Dialekt (SW-D) kommt *räubern* auch nicht vor und ich kenne das Wort nur aus der Hochsprache.

*räubern* kommt in alten Texten des öfteren vor und wird dort verwendet, um "fortgesetztes Räuber-Sein" zu transportieren.

Ein paar Zitate:

> Er gebe aber auch rechenschaft von dem kirchengolde, das er geräubert hat; ... [Schriften der Universität zu Kiel, 1873]
>
> ... Reiche von einem Wütrich zusammen geräubert zerfallen wieder unter der  Herrschaft des Sones

*räubern* wird auch in der Jägersprache verwendet, um im Tierreich die Tätigkeit eines *Raub*tiers zu beschreiben:

> Fuchs und Marder pflegen in Hühnerställen zu räubern und müssen kurz gehalten werden.

In der Alltagssprache kenne ich das Wort überwiegend als verharmlosendes Necken im Sinne von *stibitzen* oder *mopsen*, wenn sich Kinder Dinge aneignen, die sie eigentlich nicht nehmen sollen, oder als Verharmlosung von "Obst klauen":

> Die Kinder! Die Racker haben mir wieder alle Kekse aus der Dose geräubert!
>
> Die Nachbarskinder haben wieder in Müllers Johannisbeeren geräubert.

Ich habe das Wort auch schon als verharmlosendes Synonym für *wildern* (z.B. in nicht zugeteilten Vetriebsregionen bei Handelsvertretern) gehört:

> Der Müller hat wieder in meinem Bezirk geräubert und der Firma Maier eine Maschine verkauft.

Es gibt ein Gesellschaftsspiel des Ravensburger-Verlags namens "[Räubern](https://www.ravensburger.de/spielanleitungen/ecm/Spielanleitungen/Raeubern.pdf?ossl=pds_text_Spielanleitung)", in dem das Verb logischerweise auch vorkommt.

Zusammenfassend: Das Wort *ist* in der Alltagssprache tatsächlich schwach gängig, scheint ursprünglich aus dem Norden von Deutschland zu stammen, aber wird in der ursprünglichen Bedeutung praktisch nicht mehr verwendet.

Comment: Beim Räuberrommé diskutiert man auch, wann man räubern, nicht wann man rauben darf.